# Git remote to own server

Tags: git, debian

I have own remote server and I want to push changes which I've made in my code straight into it. I've initiated git inside remote server and tried to access by SSH. While SSH seem to be worknig okay, git throws me an error when attempting to git push.

```
fatal: '/home/admin/web/site.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

But repository exists, directories were made and I'm trying to access by user-owner of those directories. I'm totally stuck. Can you guide me where can be a problem?

My git remote request look as

```
admin@192.168.0.1:/home/admin/web/site/public_html/.git
```

Comment: Try `ssh admin@192.168.0.1 ls -lAF /home/admin/web/site/public_html/.git` — does it work?

Comment: Hm, it says - ls: cannot access '/home/admin/web/site/public_html/.git': No such file or directory. Still don't get the reason what an issue

Comment: access rights of public_html folder is drwxr-x--x and most of files inside(which were generated by git init --bare) only different is config, description and HEAD those are -rw-r--r--

Comment: `git init --bare` inits a repo in **the current** directory, it doesn't creates subdirectory `.git`. So your `home/admin/web/site/public_html/` is the repository.

Comment: What is output of `git config --local remote.origin.url` and `ssh admin@192.168.0.1 'ls -d ~/web/site/.git'`?

Comment: I've tried ssh admin@192.168.0.1 ls -lAF /home/admin/web/site/public_html and it worked like charm

Comment: git config --local remote.origin.url - its refers to my bitbucket repo. ssh admin@192.168.0.1 'ls -d ~/web/site/.git' - worked and didn't respond

Comment: phd, THANK YOU SO MUCH removing /.git at the end and it worked :3

Comment: @RedEclipse Please be warned all files in `…/public_html/` are accessible from the web so anyone who can guess filenames (for a bare git repo they are quite guessable) can download the repo. The recommended way is to create a repo at leas one level higher and add/commit `…/public_html/`.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind, thanks